# eBay API GetCategoryFeaturesRequest returns 'Unsupported API call' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ebay-api, typhoeus

I am trying to get `CategoryFeatures` using `Typhoeus::Request` from eBay API. I am using Ruby Version 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.3 with Ubuntu Server 11.04.

My code is below:

```
xml = <GetCategoryFeaturesRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"> 
<RequesterCredentials>
<eBayAuthToken> MY_eBayAuthToken </eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
</GetCategoryFeaturesRequest>


header = {
"X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME" => my_devID,
  "X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME" => my_appID,
  "X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME" => my_certID,
  "X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME" => "GetCategoryFeatures",
  "X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL" => "1.3.0",
  "X-EBAY-API-SITEID" => 1,
  "Content-Type" => "text/xml",
}
url = "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll "
res = Typhoeus::Request.post(url, :body => xml, :headers => header )
```

I got this error:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>
<GeteBayOfficialTimeResponse xmlns=\"urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents\">
<Timestamp>2012-07-05 06:41:28</Timestamp>
<Ack>Failure</Ack><Errors>
<ShortMessage>Unsupported API call.</ShortMessage>
<LongMessage>The API call \"GeteBayOfficialTime\" is invalid or not supported in this release.</LongMessage>
<ErrorCode>2</ErrorCode>
<SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
<ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
</Errors>
<Build>14991382</Build>
</GeteBayOfficialTimeResponse>
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Try to test your XMl in the test tool :
https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/build-test/test-tool/default.aspx

I run this XML and it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetCategoryFeaturesRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
<eBayAuthToken> my_Token </eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
</GetCategoryFeaturesRequest>
```